# Multiple UtilTranslatePathList errors when restarting Ubuntu on WSL after a shutdown

Tags: shutdown, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After performing a `sudo systemctl poweroff` in Ubuntu in WSL and restarting, I'm seeing:

```
<3>WSL (814) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2671: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7
<3>WSL (814) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2671: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
<3>WSL (814) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2671: Failed to translate C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
<3>WSL (814) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2671: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\dotnet\
...
```

Ubuntu starts, but no Windows drives are mounted into WSL.  In addition, Ubuntu exits a short while later.  After restarting, everything seems fine.

What's going on, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short answer:*

- You still shouldn't use Linux shutdown methods on a WSL2 distribution.
- You are ultimately going to need to `wsl --shutdown` and restart in order to fully recover.

*More details:*

Under the updated WSL that provides Systemd support, you can now run certain "shutdown" commands, but that doesn't mean you *should*.  This includes:

- `sudo systemctl poweroff`
- `sudo systemctl halt`
- `sudo systemctl reboot`
- Choosing any of the related Power-off or restart options in a Desktop Manager (Gnome, Xfce4, and others).

In all of these cases, Systemd replaces itself with the `systemd-shutdown` (see man page for more details), which continues running even after WSL reports that the distribution is no longer running (via `wsl.exe -l -v`).

I'm taking a bit of a guess here, but when WSL attempts to restart Ubuntu, it seems that it can't load its own `init` because PID1 is still "occupied" by `systemd-shutdown` (or perhaps because `systemd` isn't there to call it).

```
$ ps -fp 1
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  1 22:23 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-shutdown halt --timeout 90000000us --log-level 6 --log-target console
```

As a result, much of the "normal" WSL startup does not occur.  This includes the Windows drive mounts as well as the `binfmt_misc` registration that allows WSL to run Windows commands.  But not, apparently, the attempt to append the Windows path to the Linux path in the base environment.

After the timeout (90 seconds) that you see in the command arguments above, `systemd-shutdown` will terminate, and the WSL distribution will terminate (again) with it.

You could also terminate with `wsl --terminate <distro_name>` from PowerShell.

In either case, the newly restarted Ubuntu will not exhibit the error messages listed in the question.

*However*, you will still need to `wsl --shutdown` and restart before you will regain access to the ability to run Windows commands.  The "corruption" of `binfmt_misc` will actually extend to *all* WSL2 distributions running on your system until a `wsl --shutdown`.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `wsl --shutdown` that fixed my issue. my redis server process stopped responding and closing & re-opening a terminal didn't do it. `sudo shutdown` also didn't work and got me here, but what I really needed was `wsl --shutdown`